# add if condition in checkbook in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, razor

i need same like if condition in Check box using HTML.
like if checkbox has some value then its checked otherwise unchecked.

Code

```
<label><input type="checkbox" name="SelectedRoles[]" value="@role.Id" @if (Model.SelectedRoles.Contains(role.Name)) { <text> checked="checked" </text> } />
```

Comment: Why not just use a `Html.Checkbox()` or `Html.CheckBoxFor()`?

Comment: I think CheckBoxFor is a better solution to this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use an `if` block, just have a single expression which conditionally outputs something.

Taking it a step at a time... Essentially, in Razor, any value after an `@` will be output.  For example:

```
@someVariable
```

That "value" can also be the result of an expression, such as a function call.  For example:

```
@someFunction(someVariable)
```

If your expression contains multiple tokens, just do what you would do in any C# code and wrap it in parentheses:

```
@(1 + 1)
```

Using all of this, the same is true of your conditional output using the [ternary operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator).  Simply use the ternary operator to write your expression, and wrap the whole thing in a `@()` to output its result:

```
@(Model.SelectedRoles.Contains(role.Name) ? "checked=\"checked\"" : string.Empty)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try @helper for any conditions like above :

```
@model MyProject.Role 
@helper checkRole(Role role) { 
                if (Model.SelectedRoles.Contains(role.Name))
                {
                      <input type="checkbox" name="SelectedRoles[]" value="@role.Id" checked />     
                } else{
                       <input type="checkbox" name="SelectedRoles[]" value="@role.Id"/>     
                }
}
```

and than call your method from your html like that :

```
 @checkRole(role)
```

Answer (score -1):

You cannot write logic like that in HTML, you have to use Javascript.

Try something like that:

```
let checkboxElement = document.getElementsById('elementId');

window.onload = function() {
    let myValue = 'someValue';
    if (checkboxElement === myValue) {
        checkboxElement.checked = true;
    } else {
        checkboxElement.checked = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: The OP is using Razor: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-pages/overview/getting-started/introducing-razor-syntax-c

Comment: Thanks i wasnt familiar with this syntax